# Power Query table to SQL Server by R script,why is that.0 extra

Tags: sql-server, powerquery, rscript

[image]

In Power Query Editor, the text string is: 123547126811

Why is the text string in SQL Server: 123547126811.0?

R Script:

```js
library(RODBC)
conn <- odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server}; server=localhost;Database=**;uid=uid;pwd=password")
odbcClearError(conn)
sqlSave(conn, dataset, tablename="tmp",rownames=FALSE, safer=FALSE, append=TRUE,fast=TRUE)
close(conn)
```

Comment: Most likely because it's not a **string** - but a number ....

Comment: The type in Power Query is `any` (that's the "abc 123" you see), so you might get an unexpected conversion. Explicitly change the type of the column to either "text" or "whole number".

Comment: I change type to string("abc" in power query),but get the same result.

Comment: using format function is ok：dataset$cust_id <- format(dataset$cust_id)